# Is there an open source working RDP Client for Android?

Tags: android, open-source, rdp

Are there any fully implemented RDP clients that are open source for android? I have tried a few, and found that they are incomplete/do not work. Here are some that I have tried.

1.) http://code.google.com/p/desktoid/  ... Appears to be abandoned since 2009, and never fully implemented

2.) http://code.google.com/p/connectoid/ .. This is what desktoid is based on, also abandoned since 2009, and not fully implemented. (from what I can tell)

3.) Omindesk ( I cant find the link) ... also not fully implemented.

Has anybody found any working RDP clients for android, or any that are easy to make work? ... or perhaps, some of these do work and i'm just using them incorrectly. I'm very new to android development.

Any advice is much appreciated =). AtDhVaAnNkCsE !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?: [FreeRDP: A Remote Desktop Protocol Implementation](http://www.freerdp.com/)

> FreeRDP is a free implementation of the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP),
> released under the Apache license. Enjoy the freedom of using your
> software wherever you want, the way you want it, in a world where
> interoperability can finally liberate your computing experience.

[Thinstuff Android Client Released](http://www.freerdp.com/2013/01/29/thinstuff-android-client-released/)

> Thinstuff is proud to announce that aFreeRDP, the FreeRDP Android
> client, is now available in git master.
>
> aFreeRDP is already quite mature and comes with a lot of nice
> features:
>
> - Built-in help for touch pointer and gestures
> - A touch pointer for easier user input within a session
> - Gestures for common input tasks like scrolling, zooming, etc.
> - Custom keyboard views for advanced user input (i.e. common shortcuts like Win+E)
> - A flexible connection management UI allowing to quickly connect to a host as well as handling a large list with multiple predefined
>   connections
>
> The build integrates seamlessly into FreeRDPs build system – you just
> have to install the Android NDK/SDK and ant. For detailed instructions
> on how to build aFreeRDP refer to docs/README.android.

Comment: Yes. They finally released android port. Thanks.